# DotLiquid - checking for string "null or empty"

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotliquid

I'm using [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) for some e-mail templates in my ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms app, and I'm trying to exclude a certain section of one of my e-mail templates if a given string in the data object I bind to the template is null or empty.

Checking for NULL works quite nicely:

```
{% if MyString != null %}

Some fancy label: {{ MyString }}
{% endif %}";
```

However, whatever I've tried to also include the *empty* string in this test has failed so far:

```
{% if MyString != null or MyString == empty %}

{% if MyString != null or MyString == '' %}
```

How can I check for "if this string is null or empty" ??

Comment: You should probably use double quotes (`MyString == ""`), the other fault is likely in your logic. You say "If MyString is NOT null, or MyString is '' (empty), then show this area" essentially. I think you mean: `{% if MyString != null and MyString != "" %}`

Comment: @mark_s Did you modify your statement as I suggested? (`{% if MyString != null and MyString != "" %}`)

Comment: @EBrown: sorry - I missed that - and **yes**, now it works! Please post as answer so I can accept it !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After discussion in comments, it was a simple logic mistake.

`{% if MyString != null and MyString != "" %}`

Comment: Thanks for an extra pair of eyes to make even this bug shallow :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are some built in functions to handle this.

[String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm going to assume it will look like {% if String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString) %}. But I've never actually used this library so I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks, Bradley - yes, indeed, that syntax just works - great to know! The DotLiquid documentation is a bit thin at times, and the more generic Liquid docs of course don't mention .NET specifics.... great to know these function are available in DotLiquid and work as expected!

Comment: @BradleyUffner Are you sure this works? Because it's not working for me, but the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be:

```
MyString == String.Empty
```

Just looking at how DotLiquid evaluates expressions:
https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/Condition.cs

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-( Same result - even though my data string is `string.Empty`, the section I want to exclude is still showing up in the result